# Is there a way to lock down a LightSail load balancer to a public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a special use case where a department needs a Wordpress website but I want it locked down to a corporate IP. Is this possible? I see I can lock down an instance but I don't see an option to restrict access to the load-balancer.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock down?"? Restrict access using security groups to specific IP from your work?

Comment: Correct. I'm used to having the ability to attach a security group to a load balancer. I used the term "lock down" because I'm aware of some people using WAF to restrict access to some resources.